# Determine convergence/divergence of $\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I want to do this, without actually having to compute the integral and se if it attains a fixed value. So I started by rewriting the integral to

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1/2}} \ dx$$

and noticing that $1-x\geq0$ in the interval $[0,1].$ Setting $1-x=\alpha$ I get $$\int_{1}^{0}\frac{1}{\alpha^{1/2}} \ d\alpha=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\alpha^{1/2}} \ d\alpha$$ Which is convergent according to the $p-$test.

Is the reasoning correct?

Comment: How did you 'rewrite' the integal? The original is divergent whereas the 'rewritten' is convergent,

Comment: I don't follow the first step. You've changed the integrand. You need to justify why its convergence is equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Editing!

Comment: Yes this is fine. Given the plethora of $p$-tests, it would be useful to cite the result on which you are relying i.e., the integral $p$-test which implies convergence as $p=\tfrac12  < 1$. It also might be a useful exercise to prove it without the integral test though; just pull the improper limit out and evaluate the integral.

Comment: @adfriedman - Thank you!

Comment: The integral of a positive function cannot be negative. You missed a further sign change given by the differential.

Comment: Don't forget to change the bounds of the integral when you make the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

$$I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1/2}} \stackrel{(u=1-x)}{=}-\int_{0}^{1}u^{-1/2}\mathrm{d}u=$$
Let $\int x^adx=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1},$ then
$$-\frac{u^{-\frac{1}{2}+1}}{-\frac{1}{2}+1}$$
back $u=1-x$
$$I = -2\sqrt{1-x}+C$$
Also 
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(-2\sqrt{1-x}\right)=-2,\quad\lim _{x\to (-1)}\left(-2\sqrt{1-x}\right) = 0$$
then

> $$ I = \quad \int _0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx=0-\left(-2\right) = 2$$